# How to check checkbox on first click

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to check checkboxes ”Vorträge”, ”Reisen”, ”Exkursionen” on click on link „to Vorträge”, „to Reisen”, „to Exkursionen”. But they only get activated  after the second click on link. How can i check the checkbox on first click?

```js
$(".nav-link").click(function(e) {
    var target = window.location.hash;
    var $targeta = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $targeta.offset().top - 100
        }, // set offset value here i.e. 100
        900,
        'swing',
        function() {
            window.location.hash = target - 40;

        });
    $targeta.prev().prop('checked', true);

});
```

```css
#content__vortraege, #content__reisen,  #content__exkursionen  {
    display: none;
}

#tab1:checked ~  #content__vortraege, #tab2:checked ~  #content__reisen,  #tab3:checked ~ #content__exkursionen {
    display: block;
}

label{
    display:block;    
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

input{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="nav-link" href="test_anchor_2.html#vortraege">to vorträge</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link" href="test_anchor_2.html#reisen">to reisen</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-link" href="test_anchor_2.html#exkursionen">to exkursionen</a></li>
</ul>
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
<label id="vortraege" for="tab1">Vorträge</label>
<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label id="reisen" for="tab2">Reisen</label>
<input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label id="exkursionen" for="tab3">Exkursionen</label>
<div id="content__vortraege">
  <p>Vorträge Vorträge Vorträge Vorträge Vorträge Vorträge Vorträge Vorträge Vorträge </p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
</div>
<div id="content__reisen">
  <p>Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen Reisen</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p id="test">anchor_target</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
</div>
<div id="content__exkursionen">
  <p>Exkursionen Exkursionen Exkursionen Exkursionen Exkursionen Exkursionen Exkursionen Exkursionen Exkursionen </p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
  <p>some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links, some text to test anchor links</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i mean on click on ”.nav-link” instead of ”to Vorträge" …

Comment: Please show html !

Comment: here it is:www.flatland.info//various/test_anchor_2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you're retrieving the hash from the `window.location`, which updates only after the click.

You should update your code like so:

```
$(".nav-link").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault()
     var target = this.hash;
     // rest of the code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, your hash values are "vortraege", "reisen", "exkursionen".

Then in your JavaScript you try to subtract 40 from these strings:

```
window.location.hash = target - 40;
```

This causes your hash to get set to `NaN` (not a number) because `"vortraege" - 40` is `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution too, this is an important aspect to get my code clean!